# spamd is using a LOT of CPU credits on my AWS EC2 instance

Tags: cpu, amazon-web-services, spamassassin

I've got a EC2 micro instance on AWS and running spamassassin.  It's been consistently using about 0.5 CPU credits within a 5 minute period lately.  (This means that my CPU is running at 50% over a 5 minute period).

Is there a way to either reduce the frequency that spamd runs or reduce the overall amount of CPU that it utilizes?

Thanks!

EDIT: This post incorrectly stated that fail2ban was causing the CPU usage.  After turning it off, it was still using a lot of CPU credits and found the other culprit.

Comment: Note that 1 CPU credit = 1 core for 1 minute, so 0.5 credits in 5 minutes is 0.1 credit per minute, or 10% CPU... not 50%.  Any instance not at 0% is *always* using credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spamd is not something which is scheduled.  Its run whenever a process calls it.

There is no simple bullet, and a lot of the answer is "it depends on your setup", but (assuming you have a normallish email server/user profile) you can greatly drop the amount of email your server needs to process by introducing grey-listing.

(Greylisting is a lightweight way to drop incoming spam, typically it drops about 80% of spam, and typically most email is spam, so it can make quite a difference.   It works by allowing other servers to connect, send the from and to address, and if it does not recognise these it adds them to a list and closes the connection - legitimate mail servers are supposed to try and resend email, a lot of spam systems don't.   The downside is that when people first communicate with each other it takes longer for the first email to get through).

I would probably not advise it, but you can also try use blacklists to block email from likely spam sources before it reaches spamassassin.  This is much lighter-weight then using spamassassin  to check emails, but gives a lot of trust (maybe to much trust) to RBL's.

If your server is sending a lot of email and you are sure its all legit you may want to bypass spam filtering for outgoing mail. If someone sending email through your server is compromised though, you will get blacklisted that much faster - you might be able to somewhat work around this by introducing quotas - eg "cluebringer/policyd".

Lastly, you may be able to gut parts of spamassassin to make it less CPU intensive.  This is probably not a good idea though.

Comment: Thanks to @davidgo for your response.

I went the route of doing a DNS-based blacklist.  Since I run postfix, this was actually [relatively easy](https://www.howtoforge.com/block_spam_at_mta_level_postfix).  I would agree with you that it requires some trust with the holders that create the blacklists but since SpamAssassin uses the same blacklists, I don't think it's any more trust than I was offering already.  I am just stopping them before they can even send mail.

Comment: I'm pleased if it helped.  There is a difference between using Postfix blacklisting and Spamassassin listing - Spamassassin uses the blacklists to help it weigh the likelyhood of spam (so you can still get email from a blacklisted IP) while Postfix will block it outright.  Out of curiosity, what did this measure do to your CPU credits/usage ?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response.  I haven't checked yet.  Turns out that the large CPU usage was due to someone running a spam server on my server.  This in turn was causing spamassassin to go crazy because of all the bounces it was receiving!  No data yet on the measure to do black-list blocking at the postfix level.  Actually turns out that some blacklists block ec2 instances.